# Any optimized way of encrypting and decrypting a file inside Android

Tags: java, android, file

This is the current code im using for the encrypting and decrypting process also its works how it should be, except the time for encrypting and decrypting is way to long.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

public class EncryptAndDecrypt{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String key = "myencryptedpass123";

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("File_to_encrypt.mp4");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Encrypted_file.mp4");
        encrypt(key, fis, fos);

        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("Encrypted_file.mp4");
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("File_to_decrypt.mp4");
        decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); 

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

}

**Now im hoping for a better solution...**

Comment: Why are you bothering encrypting the MP4 file this way? Anyone who wants to can decrypt it, since your app contains the decryption key.

Comment: well this is just an mockup of the actual solution what im planning to build, so i don't bother about the security flaws right now.
Just looking for a better solution than this.

Comment: Try using a larger buffer within the doCopy function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use a bigger buffer, but encryption is mostly CPU-bound, so it is unlikely to get much faster. Additionally

- if you 'don't bother about the security flaws', it is better to give up on encryption altogether
- you are using DES, don't
- you are using a human-readable string as a key -- don't
- that code might no work once you are doing encryption and decryption with separate instance of `Cipher`
- if you are using defaults, you are setting up yourself for trouble. Use something like `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`
- why are you testing on desktop if you want this to work on Android?

And yes, if you include the key with the app, your 'DRM' is not of much use.

Comment: well i do bother about the security flaws, but not right now.
And im not testing it on a desktop environment, its Android only.
If you think my method is wrong, then please do guide me how do i secure some videos inside Android app. so only the App should be able to play the videos.

Thanks...

Comment: `public static void main()` implies a desktop environment. What device did you test on and what encryption speed did you get? How do you get the key to the app and make sure no one can extract it? You may need to think this first, and then try to implement it. If you really want to protect your content, stream it from a server, otherwise you are just making it a bit harder to copy/decode, etc.

Comment: I will keep in mind all the aspect, im using MID Tablet 8Inch for the testing purpose, `public static void main()` hell yeah its an desktop implementation method only as i said im just a beginner in this field of android development so bear with me.

Comment: "that code might no work once you are doing encryption and decryption with separate instance of Cipher" - Could you please elaborate on that Nikolay? I can't see where he is using different cipher instances and, if he was, how that could make it not to work? As long as the Ciphers were the same (ie, Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding") ) then I see no problem in creating different instances to encrypt/decrypt data.

Comment: CBC mode requires an IV. If you don't specify one, it is generated automatically. If you don't save it and pass it to other instances, you get garbage when decrypting (or a padding error).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a bigger buffer, but encryption is mostly CPU-bound, so it is unlikely to get much faster. Additionally

if you 'don't bother about the security flaws', it is better to give up on encryption altogether
you are using DES, don't
you are using a human-readable string as a key -- don't
that code might no work once you are doing encryption and decryption with separate instance of Cipher
if you are using defaults, you are setting up yourself for trouble. Use something like Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")

```
public static void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    public static void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        try {
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);

            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);


            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
         throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", e);
        }
    }
```